# List of customers in customer groups

Tags: magento-1, collection, customer-group

I have around 80 different customer groups, with different prices on.

How can I find out how many customers are in any given group?

Can I make a list of all customers included in customer group?

I have this but it gives me error `Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/customer_groups.php on line 3`

**UPDATE**: adding:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
```

Fixed it.

**Update** 2:

Error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function addField() on a non-object in /domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/customer_groups.php on line 19`

Where do I have to place the code to get the result. I found this code and this supposed to be a outcome but I'm struggling implementing it.

**UPDATE 3**

This is my code, it displays almost everything exactly as I want, except, there are gaps in between the groups, also could I have a group ID with it too?

[image]

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();


$_customer = array();
$customerCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
    $_customer[$customer->getGroupId()][] = $customer->getId();
}

$_groups = array();
$groupCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection');
foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
    $_groups[$group->getId()] = $group->getCode();
}

foreach ($_customer as $groupId => $customerIds) {
    echo 'Group "' . $_groups[$groupId] . '" has ' . count($customerIds) . ' customers.<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initiate `Mage` first. Add to top of your file ...

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
```

**Edit**

Please try this ...

```
$_customer = array();
$customerCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
    $_customer[$customer->getGroupId()][] = $customer->getId();
}

$_groups = array();
$groupCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection');
foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
    $_groups[$group->getId()] = $group->getCode();
}

foreach ($_customer as $groupId => $customerIds) {
    echo 'Group "' . $_groups[$groupId] . '" has ' . count($customerIds) . ' customers.<br>';
}
```

<sup>Maybe not best-practice. This can be done in one collection using `joinLeft` on customer group table ...</sup>

Comment: @BareFeet Updated answer. You add field code belongs to Magentos admin forms and not to standalone scripts. Either add this to a custom admin grid/from our use some simple html  output for your script.

Comment: Wow, that gave me a lot of results... Pages and pages long strings. Have a look at my question, this is what I want to achieve but it's not going well for me.

Comment: @BareFeet its not really clear what you want at the end. A customergroup dropdown? Where to display? Or just a list of customers that belong to given group?

Comment: What I want, is a way of finding out how many customers are in the given groups. It's just for me to find out which groups are being used the most as I want to decrease the amount of groups. This would help me determinate which ones.

Comment: @BareFeet updated again ... if you dont need group name this shoul be enough.

Comment: Wow, your amazing! Great stuff. Could you get the customer group name there too? That would be spotless!

Comment: @BareFeet updated again.

Comment: Great, you are really clever, can you have a look at my updated question? :)

Comment: @BareFeet Please do not update frequently. Please try on your own and if you have a specific question, just open a new question.

Comment: No problem, sorry to bother you. Thank you @sv3n